# Does assigning another variable to a string make a copy or increase the reference count

Tags: python

On p.35 of "Python Essential Reference" by David Beazley, he first states:

> For immutable data such as strings, the interpreter aggressively
>   shares objects between different parts of the program.

However, later on the same page, he states

> For immutable objects such as numbers and strings, this assignment
>   effectively creates a copy.

But isn't this a contradiction? On one hand he is saying that they are shared, but then he says they are copied.

Answer (score 11):

An assignment in python never ever creates a copy (it is technically possible only if the assignment for a class member is redefined for example by using `__setattr__`, properties or descriptors).

So after

```
a = foo()
b = a
```

whatever was returned from `foo` has not been copied, and instead you have two variables `a` and `b` pointing to the same object. No matter if the object is immutable or not.

With immutable objects however it's hard to tell if this is the case (because you cannot mutate the object using one variable and check if the change is visible using the other) so you are free to think that indeed `a` and `b` cannot influence each other.

For some immutable objects also Python is free to reuse old objects instead of creating new ones and after

```
a = x + y
b = x + y
```

where both `x` and `y` are numbers (so the sum is a number and is immutable) may be that both `a` and `b` will be pointing to the same object. Note that there is no such a guarantee... it may also be that instead they will be pointing to different objects with the same value.

The important thing to remember is that Python never ever makes a copy unless specifically instructed to using e.g. `copy` or `deepcopy`. This is **very** important with mutable objects to avoid surprises.

One common idiom you can see is for example:

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, pts):
        self.pts = pts[:]
    ...
```

In this case `self.pts = pts[:]` is used instead of `self.pts = pts` to make a copy of the whole array of points to be sure that the point list will not change unexpectedly if after creating the object changes are applied to the list that was passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

It *effectively* creates a copy.  It doesn't *actually* create a copy.  The main difference between having two copies and having two names share the same value is that, in the latter case, modifications via one name affect the value of the other name.  If the value can't be mutated, this difference disappears, so for immutable objects there is little practical consequence to whether the value is copied or not.

There are some corner cases where you can tell the difference between copies and different objects even for immutable types (e.g., by using the `id` function or the `is` operator), but these are not useful for Python builtin immutable types (like strings and numbers).

Comment: There is a whole lot of practical consequence to this.  Consider the commonly used `if variable is None` idiom (`None` is a builtin immutable python object and it matters if the object `is None` or just looks like `None`).  You could in principle do the same thing with a string that is set aside as special.

Comment: There is actually very little practical consequence to using `if x is None` versus `if x == None`.  They will only differ in strange corner cases (e.g., where `x` is an object that defines a strange `__eq__` test).  There is even less practical need for using `is` on strings and numbers.  Relying on `is` for special "set-aside" strings/ints is not recommended because this "setting aside" is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Consider the common case where you use `if x is None:` to check if you recieved a keyword argument.  What if you want to accept `None` as a value?  You can do `SENTINAL=''; def foo(arg=SENTINAL); if(arg is SENTINAL): arg=[]` for example.  This is not implementation dependent.

Comment: Yes it is.  Try it with `func('')` and `func(sentinel)`.

Comment: Wow -- You're right.  Super interesting.  I knew the intepreter cached small integers, but I had no idea that it would reuse strings like that.  (I'm actually a little disappointed ;^).  I still stand by there being a difference between `a is None` and `a == None` (because you never know what people are going to do in `__eq__`, but apparently that distinction is a little blurred for non-singleton immutable types.  Weird.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: CPython actually reuses (interns) *all* string literals, seemingly of any length. I tried it once with two literals of the Gettysburg Address and they ended up being the same object.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, assigning a pre-existing `str` variable to a new variable name does not create an independent copy of the value in memory.

The existence of unique objects in memory can be checked using the `id()` function. For example, using the interactive Python prompt, try:

```
>>> str1 = 'ATG'
>>> str2 = str1
```

Both `str1` and `str2` have the same value:

```
>>> str1
'ATG'
>>> str2
'ATG'
```

This is because `str1` and `str2` both point to the same object, evidenced by the fact that they share the same unique object ID:

```
>>> id(str1)
140439014052080
>>> id(str2)
140439014052080
>>> id(str1) == id(str2)
True
```

Now suppose you modify `str1`:

```
>>> str1 += 'TAG'  # same as str1 = str1 + 'TAG'
>>> str1
ATGTAG
```

Because `str` objects are immutable, the above assignment created a new unique object with its own ID:

```
>>> id(str1)
140439016777456
>>> id(str1) == id(str2)
False
```

However, `str2` maintains the same ID it had earlier:

```
>>> id(str2)
140439014052080
```

Thus, execution of `str1 += 'TAG'` assigned a brand new `str` object with its own unique ID to the variable `str1`, while `str2` continues to point to the original `str` object.

This implies that assigning an existing `str` variable to another variable name **does not create a copy** of its value in memory.