# Issue with multidimensional list python

Tags: python-3.x

**python 3.3.5**. faced strange issue while working with List. In line 6th and 8th I am printing same variable but not sure why it is getting converted into uppercase

```
siblingList = [['Abc', 'Xyz', 'Def'],['Ghi','Jkl','Mno','Pqr'],['Stu', 'Pvw']]
siblingList1 = siblingList

for i in range(len(siblingList)):
    for j in range(len(siblingList[i])):
        print(siblingList[i][j])
        siblingList1[i][j] = siblingList[i][j].upper()
        print(siblingList[i][j])
```

**Output:**

```
Abc
ABC
Xyz
XYZ
Def
DEF
Ghi
GHI
Jkl
JKL
Mno
MNO
Pqr
PQR
Stu
STU
Pvw
PVW
```

Comment: What you think about this line `siblingList1[i][j] = siblingList[i][j].upper()`?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257094/how-to-change-a-string-into-uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

Since you assign

```
siblingList1 = siblingList
```

that means that `siblingList1` is the same thing as `siblingList`.
When you do

```
siblingList1[i][j] = siblingList[i][j].upper()
```

in fact you are also modifying `siblingList[i][j]` to uppercase.

Comment: Thanks Adam. but in below case also behavior could have been same but  same is not the case here. `var1 = 'abc'
var2 = var1
var2 = var1.upper()
print(var1)
print (var2)`

Comment: `upper()` returns a new string. So `var1` is `'abc'` and `var2` first becomes `'abc'` but then becomes `'ABC'` - unrelated to `var1`. In your case you are modifying the **contents** of the arrays, not the array variables themselves. Maybe this will clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11585886/466738